# Combine full post with 4 excerpt from two different post types

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get the latest post to be a full post. This post can come from two different post types 'post' and 'tutorial'. I also want to display four excerpt, two from the 'post' post type and two from the 'tutorial' post type. I don't want the full post to be duplicated in the excerpt.

I have tried using one WP_Query, and that has almost gotten me to the right point. I have also tried using multiple WP_Query, but that hasn't been so lucky.

```
$args  = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'tutorial' ),
    'post_per_page' => 5
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    $count = 0;
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        if ( $count == 0 ) { ?>

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content();

            $count ++;

        } else { ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt();
        }
    endwhile;

endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

So this code gets me really close. But the excerpt is not doing what I want. I want it to show two excerpt of 'post' and two excerpts of 'tutorial'. Now it is showing one excerpt of 'tutorial' and three excerpts of 'post'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is a bit more complex to set it in one query. I wrote a code for you with comments for each step. Please check this out.

```
// first get last published post
$last_post = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => array( 'post', 'tutorial' ),
        'numberposts' => 1
    )
);

// get two posts excluding $last_post which might be a post
$last_two_posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
        'numberposts' => 2,
        'exclude' => array($last_post[0]->ID)
    )
);

// get two tutorial excluding $last_post which might be a tutorial
$last_two_tutorials = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => array( 'tutorial' ),
        'numberposts' => 2,
        'exclude' => array($last_post[0]->ID)
    )
);

$posts = array_merge($last_post, $last_two_posts, $last_two_tutorials);

foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    // print content only for first post and excerpt for others
    if ($post->ID == $last_post[0]->ID) {
        the_content();
    } else { 
        if($post->post_type == 'post') {
            echo '<div class="post-excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="tutorial-excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>'; 
        }
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after. So this means that I don't need to use WP_Query or a while loop?

Comment: @user3403590 get_posts() is based on WP_Query, it is just a bit shorter. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Comment: Another question. Is it possible to add a div+class to the excerpts depending if they are 'post' or 'tutorial? I tried, but the divs got nested into each other. I believe that is because of the foreach loop?

Comment: I get an error with the second else after `the_content()` `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)`

Comment: well :) that is because I missed a `}` . fixed code